# Polymer paper tabs not working

Tags: polymer

I have two separate ways of setting up tabs in my application one works and one doesn't.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Both examples are inside a custom element template
This way works:

```
<paper-tabs id="clinic-tabs" selected="{{clinicId}}" attr-for-selected="cid" scrollable>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[clinics]]" filter="_shouldDisplay" observe="active use">
    <paper-tab cid="[[item.id]]">[[item.name]]</paper-tab>
  </template>
</paper-tabs>
```

This way doesn't

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{page}}" attr-for-selected="page" scrollable>
  <paper-tab page="details">Patient Details</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab page="finance">Finance Records</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab page="history">Patient History</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab page="preopp1">Pre Op Assessment</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab page="surgery">Surgery Settings</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab page="postop">Post Op Assessment</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `onTap` function in `paper-tab.html`, on the first one if I use console to output a value
`this.cid` prints the correct value.  If I put a breakpoint on the second version then `this.page` is undefined, although `this.getAttibute('page')` does return the correct value.  As a result in the second version there is no change to the `{{page}}` value and so my tabs don't do anything.

Anyone any idea how I can setup the markup on the second one so I can use the page property in my custom element to action things (actually switching between different pages using `<iron-pages>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out that the problem is the `page` property in the host element (declared inside a behavior) is `readOnly`  for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

paper-tabs does not have attr-for-selected. it works on numeric selecting. so selected = 0, selected = 1 and so on. the first one example works only because you are propably setting IDs from 0 to x.

documentation: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/elements/paper-tabs

Comment: Actually it does have at attr-for-selected, derived from `IronSelectorBehaviour`.  See my answer below which is now working once I discovered that the `page` property was read only

Comment: @akc42 cool, sorry for my mistaken answer, did not know about that and even i am working with paper-tabs so long time. Thank you for your correction